# Is it possible to separate the legend entry line into two parts in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

I would like to know if it's possible to separate the line from the legend entry into two different types of lines.

Example : imagine that you have 4 curves : solid black, solid red, dashed black, dashed red. The black curves describe the phenomenon black while red ones describe phenomenon red. The solid line determines whether we add no other contribution than the solid one and dashed means we add some dashed contribution to it. In the legend of my plots, I want only two entries : phenomenon black or phenomenon red. But I would like the legend line of each entry to be separated in two : first half is solid and second half is dashed. In the same way, is it possible to do it the other way around (one half is solid black and the other half is solid red and the other curve is half dashed black half dashed red).

For 4 curves this makes not a lot of sense. But I sometimes have to put 6 or 8 curves and the legend is then too big to be able to put it somewhere in the figure...

Currently I use this line to add my legend : 
`legend({str1,str2},'Interpreter','latex')` 
but I don't know if it's relevant to say that.

I post a picture to illustrate what I would like (note that it could be the other way around, with two styles for one line instead of two colors) : [image]

Answer (score 0):

it's not exactly what you asked for, but it's another approach:

```
styles = {'-','--'};
colors = {'r','g','b'};
colorNames = {'red','green','blue'};
styleNames = {'normal','dashed'};
hold on
% plot many lines
for ii = 1:numel(styles)
    for jj = 1:numel(colors)
        plot((1:10) + jj + ii*numel(colors),'Color',colors{jj},'LineStyle',styles{ii})
    end
end
% generate handles for the legend
h = [];
for ii = numel(colors):-1:1
    h(numel(styles)+ ii) = plot(0,0,'Color',colors{ii},'LineStyle','-');
end
for ii = numel(styles):-1:1
    h(ii) = plot(0,0,'Color','k','LineStyle',styles{ii});
end
hold off
legend(h,[styleNames colorNames]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no in built ability to do this for the Matlab legend. You can achieve something similar by manually drawing lines. This uses the [annotation arrow](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textarrow-properties.html) functionality for a figure:

```
% plot some dummy data (not connected to the manual legend!
x = linspace(-1,1);
clf; hold on; grid on
% Set up linestyles and linecolors here so that they can be (at least
% slightly) linked between the plot and the manual legend.
linestyles = {'-', '--'};
linecolors = {'k', 'r'};
% plots
plot(x,x.^2,'linestyle',linestyles{1},'color',linecolors{1}); 
plot(x,x.^3,'linestyle',linestyles{1},'color',linecolors{2});    
plot(x,x.^4,'linestyle',linestyles{2},'color',linecolors{1}); 
plot(x,x.^5,'linestyle',linestyles{2},'color',linecolors{2});
% scale the plot within the figure to leave room for legend
plotsize = [0.06, 0.20, 0.9, 0.75];
set(gca,'position', plotsize)
% x and y are original positions for the lines
x = 0.4; y = 0.1;
% dx and dy are length and vertical spacing of lines respectively
dx = 0.1; dy = 0.05;

% The main event: drawing (headless) text arrows, so that one of them can have 
% a string properly which is your legend entry label. Use x,y,dx,dy for positioning
annotation('textarrow', [x,x+dx], [y,y], ...
    'linestyle', linestyles{1}, 'color', linecolors{1}, 'textcolor', 'k', 'headstyle', 'none', ...
    'string', 'Even functions ')
annotation('textarrow', [x+dx + 0.005,x+2*dx + 0.005], [y,y], ...
    'linestyle', linestyles{2}, 'color', linecolors{1}, 'textcolor', 'k', 'headstyle', 'none')
annotation('textarrow', [x,x+dx], [y-dy,y-dy], ...
    'linestyle', linestyles{1}, 'color', linecolors{2}, 'textcolor', 'k', 'headstyle', 'none', ...
    'string', 'Odd functions ')
annotation('textarrow', [x+dx + 0.005,x+2*dx + 0.005], [y-dy,y-dy], ...
    'linestyle', linestyles{2}, 'color', linecolors{2}, 'textcolor', 'k', 'headstyle', 'none')
```

Result:

[image: plot]

Note the positioning is done with normalised (between 0 and 1) values, so they stretch with the figure. Dealing in pixels can be easier to visualise if your plot is of a fixed size, this can be done by changing the `units` argument of the various graphics objects when resizing them (see the docs linked above for annotation arrow).

Comment: There is no way of knowing the properties of the legend itself ? Like for example the size of the line drawn in the legend, the space between the surrounding box of the legend and the lines themselves,... things like that so that I could get at least a position from which to draw some annotation like you did. I could not find it by myself but I guess there is so much I don't know about matlab that there must be a way of finding these parameters.

Comment: In short, I don't think so.